# Generating PDF byte array

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, filestream, memorystream

I have a static method like this and I am using ITextSharp to generate PDF..

```
public static byte[] createPDF(string htmlstr) {
            var  html = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
             <!DOCTYPE html 
                 PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""
                ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">
             <html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en"" lang=""en"">
                <head>
                    <title>Minimal XHTML 1.0 Document with W3C DTD</title>
                </head>
              <body>
                " + htmlstr + "</body></html>";

            // step 1: creation of a document-object
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);

            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();

            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a XML-stream to a file
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);

            // step 3: we create a worker parse the document
            HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

            // step 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
            document.Open();
            worker.StartDocument();

            // step 5: parse the html into the document
            worker.Parse(new StringReader(html));

            // step 6: close the document and the worker
            worker.EndDocument();
            worker.Close();
            document.Close();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[msOutput.Length];

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = msOutput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                msOutput.Close();

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
    }
```

When I was debugging, after I pass `worker.Parse(new StringReader(html))`, the `MemoryStream.Length` does not work.

I have seen some examples out there using `FileStream` but I do not want to create a new file. Why is the code erroring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem that you are running into is that by default the `PdfWriter` object will close the stream that you are writing to. `PdfWriter.GetInstance()` actually returns an object that you can set additional properties and you specifically want to call:

```
writer.CloseStream = false;
```

Your `MemoryStream` to `byte[]` to `MemoryStream` to `byte[]` confuses me, was that just a way to try to work around the above problem?

Beginning with iTextSharp 5.0.6 most of the primary classes such as `Document` and `PdfWriter` all implement `IDisposable` which, at least for me, along with the `using` pattern makes code much easier to read and debug. You also don't have to think about closing things as much. Give this a shot:

```
public static byte[] createPDF(string htmlstr) {
    var html = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
     <!DOCTYPE html 
         PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""
        ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">
     <html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en"" lang=""en"">
        <head>
            <title>Minimal XHTML 1.0 Document with W3C DTD</title>
        </head>
      <body>
        " + htmlstr + "</body></html>";


    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30)) {
        using (MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream()) {

            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a XML-stream to a file
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput)) {

                // step 3: we create a worker parse the document
                HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

                // step 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
                document.Open();
                worker.StartDocument();


                // step 5: parse the html into the document
                worker.Parse(new StringReader(html));

                // step 6: close the document and the worker
                worker.EndDocument();
                worker.Close();
                document.Close();
            }

            // Return the bytes
            return msOutput.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I see what I was doing incorrectly initially and your solution helped. I wanted to augment my question one more time. I am running into an issue of itextsharp not supporting style="display:none" css which I have all over the HTML I want to generate PDF from. Is there a way to hide some of the elements from the HTML while generating PDF? Any help will be appreciated.