# pdf is not opening by Adobe reader, created by using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf, itext, export-to-pdf

I am new in `iTextSharp` coding. I am creating pdf file in VS2010 from **html string**. The html string containing html table that I want convert it into a pdf file. I have develop a code by own, which successfully create PDF file but when I go to open file, its shows message that

> Adobe Reader could not open 'XXX.pdf' because it is either not a supported file or because file has been damage

but I am not getting where I am going wrong 
The code that I develop is as follows:

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PendingOrderItems.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        DataTable oTable = HtmlTableParser.ParseTable(hftbPdfData.Text);
        GridView oTempGridview = new GridView();
        oTempGridview.AllowPaging = false;
        oTempGridview.DataSource = oTable;
        oTempGridview.DataBind();
        StringWriter oStrWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter ohTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(oStrWriter);
        oTempGridview.RenderControl(ohTextWriter);
        StringReader oStringReader = new StringReader(oStrWriter.ToString());
        Document oDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker oHTMLWorker = new HTMLWorker(oDocument);
        oDocument.Open();
        oHTMLWorker.Parse(oStringReader);
        oDocument.Close();
        Response.Write(oStringReader);
        Response.End();
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?????

Comment: [This](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=56) works, perhaps you forgot to add content to pdf? Try to comment `oHTMLWorker.Parse()` line, same error? Btw, it say `Deprecated. please switch to XML Worker instead` [here](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html).

Comment: Ok I will see to it...

Comment: At an airport right now so I can't write too much, but see this answer for working with ASP.Net and iTextSharp, it should hopefully point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21482201/231316

Comment: You do `Response.Write(oStringReader)`; `oStringReader` is the string reader which contained your HTML and which had been read by your `oHTMLWorker`. Thus, you most likely write nothing to the response stream. Instead instantiate a `PdfWriter` for your document and send its output as response.